# How can we change the state if user is clicking outside the div

Tags: css, reactjs

I have 3 div. Which will behave like select boxes.
1st select box will open 1st list-items and close 2nd and 3rd list-items
2nd select box will open 2nd list-items and close 1st and 3rd list-items
3rd select box will open 3rd list-items and close 1st and 2nd list-items

I need if user is clicking out side of items or select boxes, then 1st, 2nd 3rd list of items should close.

I have attached a `

> [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrTAA.png)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrTAA.png

Thanks in advance

```
onlocationClick = () => {
    let currentlocationblock = this.state.openLocation;
    this.setState({
        openLocation: !currentlocationblock,
        openage: false,
        opengender: false,
        clearAllUncheck: true,
    })
}
onageClick = () => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let currentageblock = this.state.openage;
    this.setState({
        openLocation: false,
        openage: !currentageblock,
        opengender: false,
        clearAllUncheck: true,
    })
}
ongenderClick = () => {
    let currentgenderblock = this.state.opengender;
    this.setState({
        opengender: !currentgenderblock,
        openage: false,
        openLocation: false,
        clearAllUncheck: true,

    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by giving the div's in question a tabIndex of -1 so that they can be programmatically focused, without being part of the tab selections. After that, you can just use css do manipulate them how you want. You can see an example of this in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/runtime-cookies-ftvfk?fontsize=14).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I need to set the state on the click of out side of the select box.

Comment: Simply add an `onFocus` event handler for clicking in to a box and an  `onBlur` event handler for clicking away from the boxes. In these event handler functions, you can set states and do anything that's necessary.